# jquery. Clik url, insert value in input field, submit form with GET and page reload (no ajax)

Tags: jquery

1) Click on `<a href="#" id="ahryr">Year</a>`

2) jquery inserts value 1 in `$('#href_year_val').val(1);`

3) then jquery as if submits `$('#btn_update').submit();`

4) `method="GET"` so i expect to send to url `<input type="text" name="srtyr" id="href_year_val" value="" >` and page reload

I see value 1 in `id="href_year_val"`, page reloads, but url is like `http://localhost/ftr?`.

But i expect to see url like `http://localhost/ftr?&srtyr=1`

What do i need to change/correct?

Here is the code

```
<form action="http://localhost/ftr" method="GET" >

<input type="text" name="srtyr" id="href_year_val" value="" >

<br/>
<input type="submit" id="btn_update" value="Update">

<a href="#" id="ahryr">Year</a>

</form>
```

jquery

```
$('#ahryr').click(function() {
$('#href_year_val').val(1);
$('#btn_update').submit();
});
```

Tried also:

`<form id="update" action="http://localhost/ftr" method="GET" >`

jquery `$('#update').submit();`

but the same result

**Update**

Sorry incorrect data in question. All seems works. Did not work because actually instead of `<a href="#" id="ahryr">Year</a>` was `<a href="http://localhost/some-url" id="ahryr">Year</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Instead of

```
$('#btn_update').submit();
```

Try

```
$('form').submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Main problem seems was because instead `href="#"` i used some actual url